# Error while installing rack gem in ruby

Tags: ruby, linux, ansible, rack

While i am trying install rack gem using ansible, i get an error as :

```
ERROR:  Error installing rack:
        rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2
```

I have installed rack along with the gems as :

```
- name: Install Ruby Gems   become: yes   gem: name={{ item }} state=latest user_install=no   with_items:
    - rubygems-update
    - r509
    - r509-ca-http
    - rack
```

My current version if is see using ruby --version : 2.0.0p648

WHat is the problem , and if I have to update my ruby version and how can I update using ansible for Amazon Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently using the system default ruby version, therefore you are bound to the version the operating systems package management is offering you. You can use different package repositories to fetch a newer version of ruby. A better approach might be to use some ruby version management system, that allows you to have several version of ruby on your system and switch those e.g. on project level. To mention two popular of them: [RBENV](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) or [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

Answer (score 2):

The error you get while installing says: "`rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2`"  Then later you report "`ruby --version : 2.0.0p648`".  The message is telling you that your version of Ruby is too old, you need to upgrade it to at least 2.2.2 to use rack.